# Django registration signals fails to send new user a mail after activation

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I want to send a new registered user an email after filling the signup form. I'm using `Django registration (1.0)` to handle the signup process. Also I used the `simple-backend` so that user can get activated immediately after filling the signup form.

I wrote the below codes to send the new user a welcome email after signing up. From the [docs](https://django-registration.readthedocs.org/en/latest/signals.html) the author said we should use the user_activated signals. But after implementing mine, it failed to send the user a welcome mail.

Signals.py

```
from registration.signals import user_activated
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.core.mail import send_mail


@receiver(user_activated)
def my_notice(sender, user, request):
    new_person=user.email
    send_mail('Welcome On Board','Check the dashboard for more','example@example.com',[new_person,])
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File `signals.py` is not read by django. Try in `models.py` instead.

`signals.py` file is a good place to define a signal. You're hooking up to one.

Comment: but django registration is a standalone app. I doubt if this will fit in models.py, do I need to override?

Comment: You need to hook up to this signal somewhere in your's project code. In a place which django will read. A good place is related apps's `models.py` file, if you have one.

Comment: The docs say `user_activated` is not always sent. May be try to hook up to `user_registered` signal to test that?

Comment: @KrzysztofSzularz where does it say that?

Comment: @RobertGrant Here: https://django-registration.readthedocs.org/en/latest/signals.html#registration.signals.user_activated Some backends don't activate the user so the signal isn't send – it's at least how I understand this.